# Property does not exist on type 'Error' while using react query error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to display an error message if a use mutation hook from react query fails , the error i receive from react query is of type unknown

my mutation looks like this :

```
const {
    mutate: mutateRegister,
    error: errorRegister,
    isError: isErrorRegister,
    isSuccess: isSuccessRegister,
    data: dataRegister,
  } = useMutation(register, {
    onSuccess(d, v, c) {
      console.log(d);
      console.log(v);
      console.log(c);
    },
  });
```

if i also try to access the error to display the error message on screen if the value exists  i get the doesn't exist on type error message

my code looks like this :

```
 {isErrorType(errorRegister)  ? <p> {errorRegister.response?.data} </p> : null}
```

my isErrorType function is this :

```
export function isErrorType(error: unknown): error is Error {
    return error instanceof Error;
  }
```

any guidance ?
I'm using the isErrorType so i can tell ts that the error is of type error